# What does Angular performance budget type 'initial' means?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In the Angular CLI documentation for performance budgets, https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-size-budgets, we can see that the list of possible budget types are:

> - `bundle` - The size of a specific bundle.
> - `initial` - The initial size of the app.
> - `allScript` - The size of all scripts.
> - `all` - The size of the entire app.
> - `anyScript` - The size of any one script.
> - `any` - The size of any file.

I'm wondering what the 'initial' type means, exactly? The original size of source files? Or the output file without any optimization?

Comment: I always see this too when building my apps. I **think** initial is the first compression and bundle is the second and final compression algorithm. Initial is closer to a dev build and bundle for the production build. I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi, @Michelangelo, thanks for your comment here. It make sense, I think we need to dig into the source code to understand better. I'm wondering in which case we care about this initial budget size. To limit the build time?

Answer (score 1):

when you run the `ng build --prod`, you can see all the bundles. You get optimized bundles here unless you haven't changed prod properties in your angular.json file.  Please see the below image.

[image]

Here, all the files under **Initial Chunk Files** are falling into initial bundles. Ideally, the sum of the sizes of these files should be less than the threshold limit you set in the angular.json file. Otherwise, you will encounter a warning or an error.

[image]